# Broken ubuntu update on a 20.04 server. Unmet dependencies on linux-generic

Tags: apt, server, 20.04

I have just run some installs on my linux servers and two of them have hit a problem (one I fixed, the other is broken).

I'm getting

```
 sudo apt upgrade                                               6.7s  Thu 12 Nov 2020 11:37:03 PM UTC
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run "apt --fix-broken install" to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-generic : Depends: linux-headers-generic (= 5.4.0.52.55) but 5.4.0.53.56 is installed
 linux-headers-5.4.0-53-generic : Depends: linux-headers-5.4.0-53 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try "apt --fix-broken install" with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and when I try and run --fix-broken

```
    sudo apt-get -f install                                               Thu 12 Nov 2020 11:41:19 PM UTC
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-generic linux-headers-5.4.0-53 linux-image-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-53-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-5.4.0-53 linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-53-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic linux-image-generic
2 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/49.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 261 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
(Reading database ... 126536 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-5.4.0-53_5.4.0-53.59_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.4.0-53 (5.4.0-53.59) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-5.4.0-53_5.4.0-53.59_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to clean up mess surrounding './usr/share/doc/linux-headers-5.4.0-53' before installing another version: Bad message
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-53-generic_5.4.0-53.59_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-53-generic (5.4.0-53.59) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-53-generic_5.4.0-53.59_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to clean up mess surrounding './usr/share/doc/linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-53-generic' before installing another version: Bad message
Preparing to unpack .../linux-generic_5.4.0.53.56_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic (5.4.0.53.56) over (5.4.0.52.55) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-generic_5.4.0.53.56_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 failed to stat (dereference) existing symlink '/usr/share/doc/linux-generic/changelog.gz': Bad message
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-generic_5.4.0.53.56_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (5.4.0.53.56) over (5.4.0.52.55) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-generic_5.4.0.53.56_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to stat './usr/share/doc/linux-image-generic' (which I was about to install): Bad message
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-headers-5.4.0-53_5.4.0-53.59_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-53-generic_5.4.0-53.59_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-generic_5.4.0.53.56_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-generic_5.4.0.53.56_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)'
```

and now I can't do anything else with apt an this machine without it blowing up.

What do I do here please?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a corrupted disk image that was doing the damage.

fsck.ext4 on the image, and all is now well.

Comment: Hi Peter. What exactly was the solution? I have the same problem and a possibly corrupted /dev/sda2 disk. I did a fsck correcting errors. An now what can I do to upgrade?

Comment: Hi Giorgio, if you can't just run an apt-get update/upgrade now, I'd suggest its badly broken and rebuild it (that is what I eventually did on this system, restored it from a backup in this case I think from memory).

Comment: Thx Peter, I did it, but when upgrading. I  think the problems start swith :  `Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-53-generic (5.4.0-53.59) ...`

At the end I got always errors terminating with:
`dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-53-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-53-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 linux-image-5.4.0-53-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`